# When using Miranda-IM as an MSN/Skype/Yahoo client, are there any stages where messages aren't encrypted or go through an unintended server?

Tags: security, encryption, skype, instant-messaging, msn-messenger

Since the demise of GTalk a few weeks ago, we've found that MIM (http://www.miranda-im.org/, http://www.miranda-ng.org/en/) seems to be the lightest instant messaging client out there. It connects to multiple chat services (MSN, Skype, Yahoo) Our main concerns was security. Does it inherit protocols from it's connecting services, and are there any stages where texts sent aren't encrypted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. [security.se] or [su] are better suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it inherits the *protocols* from the services, otherwise it could not speak with them. It of course also has to use the servers of that service, which is always (for all stated protocols) able to read the messages. Depending on the inner construction of the service, the messages may go over the wire unencrypted at some point.

If you want security, you should look for a client with [OTR](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/) support and possibly an open chat protocol ([XMPP](http://xmpp.org/)) and run your own servers.